# Update TestFlight Android SDK used in an app

Tags: android, testflight, beta-testing

How can I **update the TestFlight SDK** used in my app?
Currently, I'm using **"TestFlight Android SDK v1.2** in my app, and I want to update it to **"TestFlight Android SDK v1.3**"

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Download the new jar and replace the version in /libs in your project? https://testflightapp.com/sdk/android/download/

Comment: @Nachi Should I've to change the app token also??

Comment: Nope, as far as I know the app token remains unchanged.

Comment: @Nachi Can u tell about to use the feedback widget of Android TestFlight Sdk??

Comment: Tell what? Please edit your question to be more clear and with more details.

Comment: @Igotsar The feedback module is currently not in the Android SDK for TestFlight. It will be implemented soon.